# How to store strings for translation in Vue project

Tags: javascript, html, string, vue.js, web-applications

I want to use two Languages in my application - so i want a dictionary like string file (kinda like in android development) where i simply store my strings with id's and can access the strings easily by id perhaps with a parameter for my language. What kind of file is easy to parse in my vue components and is suitable for my use case?

Comment: Ciao, you mean an Internationalization for your vue app? A way to change your app language?

Comment: More like a dictionary, as Owl below provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use normal js file and exporting normal object containing the strings.

However I highly recommend you to use [vue-i18n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-i18n) instead.

Install: `npm install vue-i18n`

or if you are using Vue Cli, run: `vue add i18n`

Quick usage:

```js
// If using a module system (e.g. via vue-cli), import Vue and VueI18n and then call Vue.use(VueI18n).
// import Vue from 'vue'
// import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
//
// Vue.use(VueI18n)

// Ready translated locale messages
const messages = {
  en: {
    message: {
      hello: 'hello world'
    }
  },
  ja: {
    message: {
      hello: 'こんにちは、世界'
    }
  }
}

// Create VueI18n instance with options
const i18n = new VueI18n({
  locale: 'ja', // set locale
  messages, // set locale messages
})
```

Then on your template

```html
<p> {{ $t("message.hello") }} </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can install: `npm install vue-i18n`

Than in **src** create new file:

**i18n.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n';

Vue.use(VueI18n);

/*
 * Load @/locales file with languages sets
 */
function loadLocaleMessages() {
  // Read context
  const locales = require.context('@/locales', true, /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i);
  const messages = {};
  // Find matches language set and use that one
  locales.keys().forEach((key) => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i);
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1];
      messages[locale] = locales(key);
    }
  });
  return messages;
}

// Language of the browser UI.
let language = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
// Use that
let currentLanguage = language.slice(0, 2);

// Exports VueI18n settings global
export default new VueI18n({
  locale: currentLanguage,
  fallbackLocale: 'de',
  formatFallbackMessages: true,
  silentFallbackWarn: true,
  messages: loadLocaleMessages(),
});
```

In **main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';

/*
 * START Import Internationalization - Translation
 */
import i18n from '@/utils/i18n.js';

// Use beforeEach route guard to set the language
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  // Use the language from the routing param or default language
  let language = to.params.lang;

  // Default language
  if (!language) {
    language = 'en';
  }

  // Set the current language for i18n.
  i18n.locale = language;
  next();
});
//* END Import Internationalization - Translation

// Vue App
new Vue({
  i18n,
  router,
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

In **router.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
import Login from './views/Login.vue';
import i18n from '@/i18n';

Vue.use(Router);

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,

  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: `/${i18n.locale}/`,
    },
    // Language prefix for everyone
    {
      path: '/:lang',
      component: {
        render(c) {
          return c('router-view');
        },
      },

      children: [
        {
          path: '/',
          name: 'Login',
          component: Login,
        },
        {
          path: 'home',
          name: 'Home',
          component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "Home" */ './views/Home.vue'),
        },
        
      
        {
          path: '*', // Fullback path
          redirect: '/',
        },
      ],
    },
  ],

  // Scroll always on top the Page
  scrollBehavior() {
    document.getElementById('app').scrollIntoView();
  },
});

// Set the Routers
export default router;
```

Then create folder **locales** with your locales **JSON** files.

For example:

**en.json**

```
{
  "general": {
    "search": "Search",
    "loading": "Loading..."
  }
}
```

**de.json**

```
{
  "general": {
    "search": "Suchen",
    "loading": "Laden..."
  }
}
```

**Usage:**

In template: `{{ $t('general.search') }}`

In JS: `this.$t('general.loading')`